# best way to recognize and handle integer overflow in c?

Tags: c, function, integer, long-integer, integer-overflow

I am so new in C and so far I didn't comprehend how to prevent from integer overflow, I read many articles but still I am not 100% sure!
in this case

```
int ft_sqrt(int nb)
{
    long int    sqrt;
    
    if (nb <= 0)
        return (0);
    if (nb == 1)
        return (1); 
    sqrt = 1;
    while (sqrt * sqrt < nb)
    {
        sqrt++;
    }
    if (sqrt * sqrt == nb)
        return (sqrt);
    else
        return (0);
}
```

to prevent overflow should I use

> long

? what is the best practice to do that?

Comment: `long` is just a short name for `long int`. On some compilers and systems, `long` is 32 bits, on others it's 64 bits. To make sure you get the largest integer type, use `long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. If you're dealing with numbers larger than 64-bit integers can handle, then there are "bignum" libraries you can use.

Comment: OT: Avoid using the name `sqrt`, as it is a name of a standard function.

Comment: Since `sqrt * sqrt` may "overflow", you will need to check that `sqrt` is less than (or equal) the square root maximum value `long int` can hold *before* performing the operation.

Comment: In this case, you can apply knowledge of how the algorithm works. `2^16 * 2^16 == 2^32` so, if you hit `2^16`, you know you'll overflow.

Comment: Consider the merits of `while (sqrt < nb / sqrt)` — that doesn't overflow.  Check that the loop breaks or continues correctly on equality (`<` vs `<=`).  You should be able to do better than incrementing `sqrt` by one each iteration.  Look up [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), for example.

Comment: @Ouroborus: The lowest value to overflow when squared in a 32-bit `int` is 46,341, not 2^16.

Comment: In C23, there's a new header, `<stdckdint.h>` and functions to protect you from overflow — `bool ckd_add(type1 *result, type2 a, type3 b);` and `ckd_sub()` and `ckd_mul()` similarly. The functions are generic; they adapt to the types of the arguments. You can find more at the [C Standard Committee's website](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) — look for document N3054, or a more recent draft of the standard if you can find one

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, yes, that's right. I mixed up `int` and `uint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` is not certainly wider than `int` and so its use may not widen the computation.

---

To certainly avoid overflow, don't multiple, but divide.

```
int ft_sqrt(int nb) {
    int    sqrt;
    if (nb <= 0)
        return (0);
    if (nb == 1)
        return (1); 
    sqrt = 1;
    // while (sqrt * sqrt < nb)
    while (sqrt < nb / sqrt) {
        sqrt++;
    }
    if (sqrt == nb / sqrt)
        return (sqrt);
    else
        return (0);
}
```

---

Yes code takes a performance hit - yet OP algorithm has many ways for improvement)

---

Alternate code:

```
unsigned bit_width(unsigned x) {
  unsigned width = 0;
  while (x) {
    x /= 2;
    width++;
  }
  return width;
}

unsigned usqrt(unsigned x) {
  if (x == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  unsigned y = 1u << bit_width(x) / 2;
  unsigned y_previous;
  unsigned diff;
  unsigned diff1count = 0;

  do {
    y_previous = y;
    y = (y + x / y) / 2;
    diff = y_previous < y ? y - y_previous : y_previous - y;
    if (diff == 1)
      diff1count++;
  } while (diff > 1 || (diff == 1 && diff1count <= 1));
  y = (y_previous + y) / 2;
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, first of all, you need to know if you want to detect an overflow or if you could just avoid them.

To just avoid them, if you know how long `nb` can be, maybe you could see if `long` or `long long` is big enough. And, if it isn't, maybe the solution proposed by [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168) of using `while (sqrt < nb / sqrt)` is the way to making it fit in one of those types.

Now, if you really want/need to check for overflow, then you'll need to check for `square_root(MAX_NUMBER_ALLOWED) < sqrt`, where `MAX_NUMBER_ALLOWED` would depend on which type you are using. C/C++ already have constants for that, you can check them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168).